# word2vec error: '_Token' object is not iterable

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I am trying to feed sentence lists sequentially into gensim.models.Word2Vec, But it generates the TypeError: '_Token' object is not iterable. What should I do?

```
    embedding_model= Word2Vec()
    for index, sentence_list in df.iterrows():
        embedding_model = Word2Vec(sentence_list, size=100, window=5, min_count=2, workers=2)
        embedding_model.train(tokenized_contents, total_examples=len(tsentence_list), epochs=10)
```

Comment: Could you provide a full example with actual data, and also the actual copy-paste of the output?

Comment: provide complete error message too.

Comment: Do you really want to create a new `Word2Vec` model every time through your `for` loop? (Probably not.) Also, you can either provide your iterable corpus in the constructor (in which case the model will do the `build_vocab()` and `train()` for you), or leave it out of the constructor and call those yourself. But you shouldn't do both, or you'll get errors like the "cannot sort vocabulary after model weights already initialized" you report below – that's a symptom of attempting to `build_vocab()` twice.

Comment: @gojomo thank you for input. instead of looping, I used  LineSentence(lines) to import a big-size lists from a text file, but still have a key error problem. sigh...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your quick response. The error was my mistake of putting pure sentences instead of token lists. However, I am still struggling with sequential feeding to Word2Vec. Here are my sample data, code, and error:

```
tokenized_contents: ['こんにちは', '!', '掲示', '板', 'が', 'でき', 'まし', 'た', 'ね', '!', 'これ', 'から', 'も', 'よろしく', 'お', '願い', 'し', 'ます', '!']

embedding_model= Word2Vec()
for index, tokenized_contents in df.iterrows():
    embedding_model = Word2Vec(tokenized_contents, size=100, window=5, min_count=1, workers=4)
    embedding_model.build_vocab(tokenized_contents)

embedding_model.train(tokenized_contents, total_examples=len(tokenized_contents), epochs=10)

Error Msg:
Traceback (most recent call last):

    embedding_model.build_vocab(tokenized_contents)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/japan/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/base_any2vec.py", line 484, in build_vocab
    trim_rule=trim_rule, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/japan/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 1318, in prepare_vocab
    self.sort_vocab(wv)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/japan/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 1184, in sort_vocab
    raise RuntimeError("cannot sort vocabulary after model weights already initialized.")
RuntimeError: cannot sort vocabulary after model weights already initialized.
'''
```

Comment: These extra details & new error should really be part of the question. See my comment above.